# Conditional For Entry Listing Pages Only

Tags: pagination, regular-expressions, advanced-conditionals

I have some code inside a global snippet that I only want to display on a blog listing page. So the allowed URL types could be:

- /blog
- /blog/P10
- /blog/category/crackers
- /blog/author/skeletor

I do *not* want the code to display on the individual blog post pages (/blog/my-post-title).

So the pseudo-conditional would be:

- If `segment_1` equals "blog" AND

  - `segment_2` is empty
  - OR `segment_2` is pagination
  - OR `segment_2` equals "category"
  - OR `segment_2` equals "author"

The pagination is the part that's tripping me up. I know I can use [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) to use regexes, but it doesn't let me use advanced AND/OR and () operators to string cases together. Something like:

```
{if segment_1 == 'blog' AND (segment_2 == '#^P(\\d+)$#' OR segment_2 == 'category' OR segment_2 == 'author' OR segment_2 == '')}
```

Is there an add-on that will let me use regexes inside advanced conditionals, or is there another way of doing it altogether?

Comment: You can do things like AND http://stackoverflow.com/a/469951 I'd continue w/ Switchee or does it not allow this?

Comment: It's not just AND/OR though, it's also the () which groups the `segment_2` conditionals together. So it would be something like `{if segment_1 == 'blog' AND (segment_2 == '#^P(\\d+)$#' OR segment_2 == 'category' OR segment_2 == 'author' OR segment_2 == '')}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually nest Switchee tags with a special syntax, so this should work for you:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_1}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="blog"}
        {switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
            {case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''|category|author"}
            .. display your stuff ...
            {/case}
        {/switchee} 
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

Comment: I did not know that! Great, answer - thanks!

Comment: I just tried it with a [slightly different syntax](https://gist.github.com/4355362), but the content is displayed on the single-entry blog post pages. Any idea why?

Comment: My bad, I was using "case" instead of "variable" inside the `{exp:switchee}` tag.

Comment: Glad you sorted it.